# How can I skip to value to specific key in JSON object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So I am dealing with an object that looks a bit like this:

```
{
  examples: [
    { key: 'value1' },
    { key: 'value1' },
    { key: 'value1' },
    { key: 'value2' },
    { key: 'value2' },
    { key: 'value2' }
  ]
}
```

As you can see the values are ordered. I'm trying to get where the value is value2 and I'm sure there is a more efficient way than what I am doing currently, as the actual object is significantly larger and so it takes some time to reach value2.
This is the function I created:

```
function getValue2 (obj, num) {
    if (obj.examples[num] = "value2"){
        console.log(obj.examples[num]);
    }
    else {
        getValue2(obj, num + 1);
    };
};

var x = JSON.parse(obj);
getValue2(x, 0);
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

```js
const data = {
  examples: [ { key: 'value1' }, { key: 'value1' }, { key: 'value1' }, { key: 'value2' }, { key: 'value2' }, { key: 'value2' } ]
};

const res = data.examples.find(({ key }) => key === 'value2');

console.log(res);
```

To get the index of the first occurrence, you can use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

> returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it returns -1, indicating that no element passed the test.

```js
const data = {
  examples: [ { key: 'value1' }, { key: 'value1' }, { key: 'value1' }, { key: 'value2' }, { key: 'value2' }, { key: 'value2' } ]
};

const index = data.examples.findIndex(({ key }) => key === 'value2');

console.log(index);
```

Comment: Hey, I really like this solution. How could I get the corresponding number to the key? For example where value2 begins here it is the 3rd key in the object, so the number would be 2, but how do I get the application to get that number? (ik I worded this really weirdly idk how to explain it.)

Comment: @Sigsby I updated the answer to get the index of the first occurence

Answer (score 2):

How about using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), like this:

```
function getValue2(obj){
   return Object.values(obj.examples).find(e => e === 'value2')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is you are using a single equals `=` to check equality when it should be `==` or `===`.

As for alternative ways to run a similar function, I suggest you look up and learn about the `for` and `while` loops, as they are essential for JS.